# Maven fails to find plugin descriptor for com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:1.4.3

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile, spotify

This might be a but, but possibly just me who is missing a step or doesn't understand something.

I am trying to set up a dedicated submodule in a maven project, which sole task is to generate a docker image (this is a test project for playing around, but might use the structure for something else). But every time I try and build my submodule I get an error "Failed to parse plugin descriptor for com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:1.4.3".

I tried to smash maven with hammers of various sizes, but I can't seem to crack this nut. I did find that there is a difference between executing `mvn deploy` and `mvn dockerfile:build`. If I execute `mvn deploy`, I get the mentioned error, but executing `mvn dockerfile:build` finishes without any issues and generates a docker image as expected.
I have also tried building the extension from source, but if fails the integration tests. Running some of the tests (tried both the advanced and multi-module ones) manually results in the same error as I see in my own project.

### How to reproduce

Standing in the submodule, execute `mvn deploy`

Parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockertest</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>serverimage</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-extension</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.3</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </build>
</project>
```

Submodule pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>dockertest</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>serverimage</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-extension</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-image</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

setting.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>com.spotify</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

### What do you expect

I would expect `mvn deploy` and `mvn dockerfile:build` to both produce the docker image

### What happened instead

If I execute `mvn dockerfile:build` it produces the image without any issues.
If I execute `mvn deploy` instead, it crashes with the error message: "Failed to parse plugin descriptor for com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:1.4.3 (C:\Users\mcso.m2\repository\com\spotify\dockerfile-maven-extension\1.4.3\dockerfile-maven-extension-1.4.3.jar): No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml -> [Help 1]".

### Software:

- `docker version`: 18.03.1-ce
- Spotify's dockerfile-maven version: 1.4.3

### Full backtrace

```
>mvn -e -X deploy
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T20:33:14+02:00)
Maven home: C:\bin\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\..
Java version: 10.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.annotation.security.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.fusesource.jansi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Message scheme: color
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\bin\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\mcso\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from C:\bin\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\..\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\mcso\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\mcso\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\mcso\.m2\repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=757775, ConflictMarker.markTime=357906, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=473213, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=366369, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=2640047, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=37800937, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=6824557}
[DEBUG] com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:jar:1.4.3:
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:runtime
[DEBUG] Created new class realm extension>com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:1.4.3
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm extension>com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:1.4.3
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm extension>com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:1.4.3
[DEBUG]   Included: com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:jar:1.4.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.example:serverimage:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: [ClassRealm[extension>com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:1.4.3, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@73877e19]]
[DEBUG] Created new class realm project>com.example:serverimage:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Populating class realm project>com.example:serverimage:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   Included: com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:jar:1.4.3
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[project>com.example:serverimage:1.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.example:dockertest:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT: [ClassRealm[extension>com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:1.4.3, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@73877e19]]
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecycle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[project>com.example:serverimage:1.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.example:serverimage:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [deploy]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< com.example:serverimage >--------------------
[INFO] Building serverimage 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.816 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-22T14:56:41+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:1.4.3 (C:\Users\mcso\.m2\repository\com\spotify\dockerfile-maven-extension\1.4.3\dockerfile-maven-extension-1.4.3.jar): No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginDescriptorParsingException: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-extension:1.4.3 (C:\Users\mcso\.m2\repository\com\spotify\dockerfile-maven-extension\1.4.3\dockerfile-maven-extension-1.4.3.jar): No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.extractPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:186)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.extractPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:186)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:244)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginDescriptorParsingException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dockerfile-maven-extension` is not a maven plugin, but a maven extension.

So you must not use it within the `<build><plugins>` section of your `pom.xml`, but within `<build><extensions>` instead:

```
<build>
  <extensions>
    <extension>
      <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
      <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-extension</artifactId>
      <version>${version}</version>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
</build>
```

(Source: [Dockerfile Maven readme on GitHub](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven))

As you are already doing this in your parent pom, you should be able to just remove the corresponding `<plugin>` element from your child pom.

Comment: This gave me just the tip that I needed to discover the error. It appears that I have been mixing apples and oranges.

You are indeed correct that `dockerfile-maven-extension` is an extension, and as such should only be in the `<extensions>` section. I need the functionality it brings, so it stays in the parent pom (as you said).
My issue was then, that I kept using `dockerfile-maven-extension` in the plugin section where I instead should have used `dockerfile-maven-plugin`. This provides the integration that I need for my tests. I didn't notice that I had used the wrong one all the time.